# PHP adding specific key values into pre-existing array

Tags: php, arrays, insert

I have an array:

```
$test = Array
        (
            ["foo"] => Array
                (
                    ["totalsales"] => 80
                    ["totalamount"] => 4
                )
         (
```

I want to add new indices with values:

```
$test["foo"][$date] = 20; // $date = 2013-06-30
$test["foo"][$date] = 40; // $date = 2013-06-25
```

The output looks like this:

```
$test = Array
        (
            ["foo"] => Array
                (
                    ["totalsales"] => 80
                    ["totalamount"] => 4
                    ["2013-06-25"] => 40
                )
         (
```

I would expect the array to look like this:

```
$test = Array
        (
            ["foo"] => Array
                (
                    ["totalsales"] => 80
                    ["totalamount"] => 4
                    ["2013-06-30"] => 20
                    ["2013-06-25"] => 40
                )
         (
```

How can this be done? Thanks and sry for my bad english.

Comment: Unless you have syntax errors, it should work fine. You're not doing something correctly. Or maybe you don't update the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't parse.

Make sure `$date` variable contains exactly what it should, since (other than syntax problems) your example works perfectly fine:

```
<?php
$test = array
(
    'foo' => array
    (
        'totalsales' => 80,
        'totalamount' => 4
    )
);

$date = '2013-06-30';
$test['foo'][$date] = 20;

$date = '2013-06-25';
$test['foo'][$date] = 40;

print_r($test);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [totalsales] => 80
            [totalamount] => 4
            [2013-06-30] => 20
            [2013-06-25] => 40
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had an error in a previous section of my code :-)